# Execute User Input at breaks from PHP to Shell

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have a php script that is called and it executes a shell command through shell_exec(). This shell command requires multiple user inputs at different stages. I am stuck with getting the interactivity piece working at each input stage.

```
This is just an example of how I imagine it working... 
<?php
$return = shell_exec('runcmd'); 

//Let runcmd run until first break
echo $return;
$userinput1 = 'foo';

//Let runcmd run until next break
echo $return;
$userinput2 = 'bar';

//Let runcmd run until nth break
echo $return;
$userinputNth = 'nth';
```

Comment: whats the big picture? i can imagine better alternatives.

Comment: I am open to alternatives, the main issue is that i didn't write the shell script but definitely need to interact with it through the web somehow.

Comment: ssh2_connect PHP extension may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To feed input to a shell command, use [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php).

```
$handle = popen('runcmd', 'w');
fputs($handle, 'foo
bar
nth
');
pclose($handle);
```

Since output is not captured, we needn't echo it.